# Limit of Composition condition when function is discontinuous

Tags: limits

We know that if $f$ is continuous at b where b = $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x)$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(g(x))$ = $f(b)$ . Suppose now $f$ is discontinuous at $b$ or $b$ isn't in $dom(f)$, but $lim_{x \rightarrow b} f(x)$ still exists. What condition must be imposed on $g$ so that $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(g(x))=\lim_{x \rightarrow b } f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the existence of both limits, $\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)=b$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to b}f(x)$. This is particularly easy to prove if you use the topological definition of limit.

Answer (score 0):

Only existence of limits is not enough, so let me bring exact theorem:

Let's assume, that exists, finite or not, limits $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=b$ and $\lim\limits_{y\to b}F(y)$. Also assume, that exists some deleted neighbourhood of point $a$, in which $f(x)\ne b$. Then exists limit for compound function $F\circ f$ and holds
$$\lim\limits_{y\to b}F(y)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}F(f(x))$$

If we omit condition on $f$, then can be considered **counterexample**:
$$F(y)=\begin{cases}0,&y\ne0 \\
1,& y=0
\end{cases}$$
and $f(x)\equiv0$ everywhere. Of course composition $F\circ f$ is constant, so $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}F(f(x))=1$, but on another hand $\lim\limits_{y\to 0}F(y)=0$.