$\sin(f(x))/f(x)$ goes to $1$ when $f(x)$ goes to $0$
Let $f(x)$ be differentiable, $f(x) \neq 0$ on an open neighborhood of $0$ and $f(0)=0$. $g(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. I claim that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{g(f(x))}{f(x)} = 1$. First of all, define
$$
\hat{g}(x) =  
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = 0 \\
\frac{\sin x}{x} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, $\hat{g}$ is continuous at $0$, so $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(f(x)) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \hat{g}(f(x)) = \hat{g}\left(\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)\right) = \hat{g}(f(0)) = \hat{g}(0) = 1.$$
I think this proof is right. please check my proof and suggest any other simple proof. thanks in advance

"$\lim\limits_{f(x) \to 0}$" isn't really standard notation/terminology. Do you have a definition of it that you are working with?

ah thank you for your comment, you are right. notation should be replaced with $limit_{x \rightarrow 0}$

You should use theorem about limit of composition https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4430705/limit-of-composition-condition-when-function-is-discontinuous/4430723#4430723

Techincally, $\lim_{f(x)\to 0}$ is meaningless. For example, let's say $f(1)=f(0)=0,$ then what is $x$ doing when $f(x)\to0?$ Does it approach zero or one or alternate between both? The notation only allows a variable to approach zero.

@LYJ - If that's the case then you should edit your question to correct the mistake.

Limits and function composition are commutative when the functions considered are continuous. I'm sure this has been asked before on this site.
